# Require jar for Oracle XML XDK

Tags: java, xml, oracle, jar

I am trying to *compare two XML files in Java*. I also found the code here

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDK/adx_j_diff.htm#ADXDK198

But I could not find the jar file for `oracle.xml.diff.DiffOp` and `oracle.xml.diff.DiffOpReceiver`.

Comment: **Oracle XML Developer's Kit for Java is included with Oracle database**. They are located in **$ORACLE_HOME/lib** directory. You can get the jar files from links I mentioned in my answer. Have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Oracle XML Developer's Kit for Java is included with Oracle database.** These is no external link for these libraries to download. Look at this [Installing XDK](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDK/adx_overview.htm#ADXDK19054). This link will show you where is the jar for XDK located in Oracle Database see [Installing Oracle XDK for Java Components](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDK/adx_j_gs.htm#ADXDK19065).

I found [Maven Dependency for Oracle-xdb& Oracle-xsql](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven/mule/dependencies/maven1/). Also these is one link which contains [oracle.xml.differ.Diff - Jars](http://www.findjar.com/class/oracle/xml/differ/Diff.html). I am not sure about the jar given in [oracle.xml.differ.Diff - Jars](http://www.findjar.com/class/oracle/xml/differ/Diff.html) are from which version of Oracle. But, you can checkout them too.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi I checked all the jar files but unable to find the class oracle.xml.diff.DiffOp and oracle.xml.diff.DiffOpReceiver.. is there oracle version problem or oracle changed this class?? if You got ,please mail me at aman86851@gmail.com thankyou

Comment: Have u tried with **oracle.xml.differ.Diff - Jars** ? I think these jars also provide the same features. Checkout the latest version of Oracle for these classes. Whether these classes r deprecated by Oracle ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a tricky work around but if this is useful to someone, well just my two cents.

1. Search for oracle.xml.differ.Diff in findjar.com, then you get the
   jar name:  xml.jar and xmlcomp.jar
2. Search for "xmlcomp.jar index of" in google,
   then you will get a public route in somepage with the publicated non
   restricted jar ready to download.
3. I got this [xml.jar](http://216.178.102.59/content/oracle/product/11.2/client_1/lib/xml.jar) and this [xmlcomp.jar](http://216.178.102.59/content/oracle/product/11.2/client_1/lib/xmlcomp.jar), and even this [xmlcomp2.jar](http://216.178.102.59/content/oracle/product/11.2/client_1/lib/xmlcomp2.jar) under [`oracle/product/11.2`](http://216.178.102.59/content/oracle/product/11.2/client_1/lib/) folder. Maybe the link will die over the time, but you can always get the jar doing step 2.

Answer (score 0):

Info for people like me, who are only checking for the Jar:
First of all, please tell that, this is a commercial licence product. That's the reason, we are unable to found the XML.jar in internet. Even in documentation also, they are always mentioning it is under the lib folder. But, you can't get the lib folder directly accessible on internet.

Comment: Please put your remark under comment section of question or answer, instead of writing in answer section. As you have raised the point regarding question, comment will provide more easy way for other readers to let know the caveat associated with the question. As answer section is solely for giving solution to the question.